# iText How to merge cells when the data in the cells is the same

Tags: c#, itext

How to merge cells when the data in the cells is the same? I want to merge subsequent cells with the same value, such as `Header 1`.

[image]

Comment: iText doesn't check for equal cell contents and join such cells for you, so you have to check that yourself. As soon as you have determined, though, that the current row is the start of a run of **n** rows with the same value in the leading cell, you can add that cell once (and only once) with a  `Rowspan` value of **n** to achieve something like you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mkl explained in his comment, iText will not automatically detect and merge cells with equal content. You have to do those checks in your data and set the necessary rowspan values accordingly. The exact implementation will depend on the data structure of your table data, but conceptually it will look like this:

```cs
PdfWriter w = new PdfWriter("SO67333436.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(w);
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

String[,] tabledata = new String[,] {
    { "Header 1", "Row 1" },
    { "Header 1", "Row 2" },
    { "Header 1", "Row 3" },
    { "Header 2", "Row 4" },
    { "Header 2", "Row 5" },
    { "Header 3", "Row 6" },
    { "Header 3", "Row 7" },
    { "Header 3", "Row 8" },
    { "Header 3", "Row 9" }
};

// Add the table without any preprocessing
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Table without any rowspans:"));
Table regulartable = new Table(2);
for (int r = 0; r < tabledata.GetLength(0); r++)
    {
    for (int c = 0; c < tabledata.GetLength(1); c++) {
        String celldata = tabledata[r,c];
        regulartable.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(celldata)));
    }
}
doc.Add(regulartable);

doc.Add(new Paragraph("Table with rowspans:"));
Table headertable = new Table(2);
int nextheader = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < tabledata.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < tabledata.GetLength(1); column++)
    {
        String celldata = tabledata[row, column];
        // first column
        if (column == 0)
        {
            // skip cells that have been merged
            if (row >= nextheader)
            {
                int rowspan = 1;
                // Check how many subsequent rows have the same cell content
                while (row + rowspan < tabledata.GetLength(0) && celldata.Equals(tabledata[row + rowspan,column]))
                {
                    rowspan++;
                }
                nextheader = row + rowspan;
                // Add the cell with the appropriate rowspan
                Cell cell = new Cell(rowspan, 1).Add(new Paragraph(celldata));
                headertable.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
        // other columns
        else
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(celldata));
            headertable.AddCell(cell);
        }
    }
}

doc.Add(headertable);
doc.Close();
```

Resulting output:

[image: PDF output]